# Simulink Mega2560 Serial Receive

Tags: arduino, serial-port, ascii, simulink

I need help with block "Serial Receive" of Simulink Support Package for Arduino. I'm decoding received bytes with "V2 Ascii Decode" but data is coming in single bytes and I don't know how to convert it to expected numeric value e.g., I'm sending to Arduino "123" and in Simulink I've get separately "1" then "2" then "3". How could I decode this to original value?

Comment: Did you insert any separators? How should your simulink model detect the end of a number?